# Adding library to Xcode project

Tags: xcode, macos

I'd like to add the `libevent` library to my Xcode project. I want to include it in the executable, because `libevent` isn't installed by default on Mac OS X.

I can compile the library from source using `./configure && make`. I expected to find a `.a` library file, but there isn't. What do I do then? What files are relevant and how do I add them to Xcode?

Sorry for this very basic question, but I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

First off, let's find out if your library truly got built.  In the terminal, type in `cd /` and then `find . -name libevent\* -print` and see if the path for your libevent.a file actually appears.

If you can't find it, try running `sudo make install` from the top level of the library source code and then the library may end up getting installed in `/usr/local/lib` or some other appropriate place.

Once you do find the library, you can drag & drop it into your Project's list of Files in Xcode.  Or you can include `-levent` in the link settings for your project.

Comment: Yes, it actually _did_ get built, but in a hidden directory. If I do `sudo make install` and then just include it as always, will the library get copied into my executable?

Comment: If it is a static library (i.e. a file that ends with `.a`) then **YES** it will be linked in with your binary. If it is a dynamic library, then you have to do an explicit copy and include the library into your built product.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Xcode has this nasty "feature" that if it sees both dynamic and static versions of a library, it will always link against the dynamic one, even you specify the static one (.a) in your project. There's no way to override this "feafure" and you have to move or delete the dynamic one out of the library search paths.